# SiriKit INSendMessageIntent skip confirm delegate

Tags: ios, swift, message, sendmessage, sirikit

I've been working on **SiriKit** for a while, and the result of my demo was not satisfied by my boss. 
By reading all the Apple documents & did my best to search online, I still can't find a way to skip the confirm step in SendMessageIntent!

---

This is my purpose:

After resolving user comments to Siri,

```
func resolveContent(forSendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, with completion: @escaping (INStringResolutionResult) -> Void) {
    if let text = intent.content, !text.isEmpty {
        if text == "Login with Touch ID" {
            completion(INStringResolutionResult.success(with: text))
        } else if text == "Change password"{
            completion(INStringResolutionResult.success(with: text))
        }
        completion(INStringResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: ["Login with Touch ID", "Change password"]))
    } else {
        completion(INStringResolutionResult.disambiguation(with: ["Login with Touch ID", "Change password"]))
    }
}
```

Skip this step "confirm",

```
func confirm(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    // Verify user is authenticated and your app is ready to send a message.

    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSendMessageIntent.self))
    let response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)

    completion(response)
}
```

And do the handle delegate directly,

```
func handle(sendMessage intent: INSendMessageIntent, completion: @escaping (INSendMessageIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    // Implement your application logic to send a message here.

    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: NSStringFromClass(INSendMessageIntent.self))
    let response = INSendMessageIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: userActivity)

    completion(response)
}
```

Hope there's someone can answer this question for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `confirm` function is optional, you don't need to implement it to be able to conform to the `INSendMessageIntentHandling` protocol, only the `handle(intent:completion:)` is required. This shows that you can skip the confirmation part.

You should just delete the `confirm` function and `SiriKit` will call your `handle` function directly, without the confirmation.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for asking. 
I've tried your way to accomplish my goal, but after delete confirm function, my Siri still confirm the message I sent. Besides deleting confirm function, is there any part I missed?

Answer (score 0):

As @Dávid Pásztor answerd.

Don't implement `confirm` function.
Don't check `User confirmation required` in YourXX.intentdefination

And you must delete previous shortcut then readd.